# How to publish Android App above 100 MB on Google Play store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How can I publish my Android application, as it is not possible to upload an application that

exceeds 100 MB on the Google Play store,

My application contains audio files in Assats Folder exceeding 100 MB in size, how can I

upload an application that is 800 MB in size on Google Play store

Answer (score 1):

**Play Asset Delivery**

Play Asset Delivery (PAD) brings the benefits of app bundles to games. It allows games larger than 150MB to replace legacy expansion files (OBBs) by publishing a single artifact to Play containing all the resources the game needs. PAD offers flexible delivery modes, auto-updates, compression, and delta patching, and is free to use. Using PAD, all asset packs are hosted and served on Google Play removing the need to use a content delivery network (CDN) to get your game resources to players.

Play Asset Delivery uses asset packs, which are composed of assets (such as textures, shaders, and sounds), but no executable code. Through Dynamic Delivery, you can customize how and when each asset pack is downloaded onto a device according to three delivery modes: install-time, fast-follow, and on-demand.

If you want to jump directly to implementing PAD in your game, see [Next step](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery#next-step-instructions).